# Converting list of objects to json array

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a List of class objects that have email address and status data members. I am trying to convert these to a json, making sure to have the "operations" word on the array.

This is my class:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string email {get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

This is my current code (not building):

```
List<MyClass> data = new List<MyClass>();
data = MagicallyGetData();

string json = new {
     operations = new {
          JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.Select(s => new {
               email_address = s.email,
               status = s.status
          }))
     }
};
```

This is the JSON I am trying to get:

```
{
  "operations": [
    {
      "email_address": "email1@email.com",
      "status": "good2go"
    },
    {
      "email_address": "email2@email.com",
      "status": "good2go"
    },...
  ]
}
```

**EDIT1**
I should mention that the data I am getting for this comes from a DB. I am de-serializing a JSON from the DB and using the data in several different ways, so I cannot change the member names of my class.

Comment: what are you actually getting?

Comment: Why are your annoying yourself with anonymous objects ? Use datacontrat instead or name attribute http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm

Comment: @ Arpit        The closest I have gotten is the same output without the operations string before the array.

Comment: I assume this was with [Json.NET from Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe this will give you what you want. You will have to change your class property names if possible.

Given this class

```cs
class MyClass
{
   public string email_address { get; set; }
   public string status { get; set; }
}
```

You can add the objects to a list

```cs
List<MyClass> data = new List<MyClass>()
{ 
   new MyClass(){email_address = "e1@it.io", status = "s1"}
   , new MyClass(){ email_address = "e2@it.io", status = "s1"}
};
```

Using an [anonymous-type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types) you can assign `data` to the property `operations`

```cs
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
   operations = data
});
```

Comment: With a few tweaks, this is the solution I went with. Thanks, appreciate it.

Comment: What, if I don't want either data or operations at the beginning?

Comment: @HafizH if you don't want "operations" at the beginning simply do: `var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(operations)`

Answer (score 4):

```
class MyClass
{
     public string email_address { get; set; }
     public string status { get; set; }
}

List<MyClass> data = new List<MyClass>() { new MyClass() { email_address = "email1@email.com", status = "good2go" }, new MyClass() { email_address = "email2@email.com", status = "good2go" } };

//Serialize
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

//Deserialize
var jsonToList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something like this:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(data);
```

Answer (score -1):

### Here is the simple code

> JArray.FromObject(objList);

Comment: To be able to understand your answer more details are needed. Currently it looks to me that this will not work.