# Converting C# List into JSON specific format

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a graph in my view which looks like this:

```
  var hourlyGraph = Morris.Bar({
            element: 'graph_bar',
            data: [
               @foreach (var item in ViewBag.HourlyGraph)
               {
                @:{device: '@item.Hour.ToString("D2"):00', geekbench:@item.Sales },
               }
            ],
            xkey: 'device',
            ykeys: ['geekbench'],
            labels: ['Sold'],
            barRatio: 0.4,
            barColors: ['#0A4D70', '#34495E', '#ACADAC', '#3498DB'],
            xLabelAngle: 35,
            hideHover: 'auto',
            resize: true
      });
```

This is a morris chart. Note how the data is set up here:

```
[
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.HourlyGraph)
{
@:{device: '@item.Hour.ToString("D2"):00', geekbench:@item.Sales },
}
]
```

And now I need to fill the chart with new data. In my Action I have created a list which contains 2 properties:

```
public int Hour {get;set;}
public int Sales {get;set;}
```

And they are stored into a list typed of:

```
var HourlyGraph = new List<HourlyGraph>();
```

Now I'd like to convert this list into a JSON format which would look something like this:

```
[
{device: '0', geekbench:5 },
{device: '1', geekbench:13 },
{device: '2', geekbench:25 },
{device: '3', geekbench:14 },
{device: '4', geekbench:16 },
]
```

Where value for device would be = hour, and geekbench = sales ...

How could I do this in C#?

Comment: Something like this would work ? 

new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<HourlyGraph>(yourList);

Comment: Did you have a look at the Newtonsoft.JSON library? You will find it on nuget

Comment: @TomDoodler yes but what confuses me here is how do I set the first string in json to be named like "device" and "geekbench" ?

Comment: @joab what about "device" and "geekbench" values, how do I place them in JSON response ?

Comment: Somethin like this would work ?
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "device")]
public int Hour {get;set;}

Comment: You can project to an anonymous object with the property names you want, e.g. `HourlyGraph.Select(hg => new { device = hg.Hour.ToString(), geekbench = hg.Sales });`

Comment: @joab done , but for the first part of code it says cannot convert type HourlyGraph into string ?

Comment: Using the Newtonsoft.JSON , look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654350/converting-list-of-objects-to-json-array

Answer (score 2):

With Json.Net and Linq it's easy:

```
string myJson = 
   JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mylist.Select(item=>
                                  new {device=item.Hour, geekbench=item.Sales}));
```

You project an anonymous type with the fields and names that you'd like, and let Newtonsoft.Json do the rest.

Comment: Ofir, this is NewtonSoft.JSON library , no ? It says it doesn't contains method "Serialize" ... ?

Comment: it's SerializeObject sorry

Comment: Ofir, another quick question, says i.Sales doens't exists ... ? Should it be item.Sales or ?

Comment: ohhh me and my typos... sure it's item

Comment: haha happens , thx a lot =D .. Btw. return type of this action should be string or JsonResponse? Or just a simple string ?

Comment: Ofir , oh my goodness I'm missing just one small thing.. The response is returned like this: [{"device":"16","geekbench":1}]   ... Device is under two quote marks but it shouldn't be... it should be just like this: [{device:"16","geekbench":1}]

Comment: Well, i'm no expert on MVC. this one will just be a string, but if you need a JsonResponse i guess you need to add the header: return this.Content(jsonString, "application/json"); also maybe the answer from Usman mixing with the Linq projection would give you the best resutls

Comment: Why shouldn't it be with quotes? that's a correct json syntax

Comment: Ofir, for some reason this graph doesn't uses quotes for the property... Not sure why =/

Answer (score 1):

since you are using mvc why not use `return Json()` it will convert the `object` to `json` string you can use it like

```
  public ActionResult Myaction()
    { 
        var HourlyGraph = new List<HourlyGraph>();


        return Json(HourlyGraph.Select(x => new {Hour=x.Hour,Sales=x.Sales }));
    }
```

Comment: Usman this looks too good to be true haha... Hold on I'll try =D

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired output by using LINQ Anonymous Type

As per example following is class

```
public class HourlyGraph
{
    public int Hour { get; set; }
    public int Sales { get; set; }
}
```

Import Namespace **System.Web.Script.Serialization** which is a Microsoft's Inbuilt Class for dealing with JSON. You will need to refer additional assembly named *System.Web.Extensions* using 'Add References'.

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

Declare List and Convert into customized JSON Format

```
        var listHourlyGraph = new List<HourlyGraph>();

        //Adding some Sample Values
        listHourlyGraph.Add(new HourlyGraph() { Hour = 0, Sales = 5 });
        listHourlyGraph.Add(new HourlyGraph() { Hour = 1, Sales = 10 });

        //Declaring JavaScriptSerialzer Object
        var serialzer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        //Using Serialize Method which returns back a JSON String
        //We are using LINQ SELECT Method to create a new anonymous return type which contains our custom return types
        string s = serialzer.Serialize(listHourlyGraph.Select(x => new { device = x.Hour, geekbench = x.Sales } ));
```

You will get the following output in 's' variable

```
[{"device":0,"geekbench":5},{"device":1,"geekbench":10}]
```

Note: *If you want to get performance optimizations then you are better using [Newtonsoft JSON](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) Library* instead of Microsoft's Default JSON Library.

Comment: Also to add if you want the JSON values as string rather than integer then use C#'s ToString() method in anoumous type. 

    e.g string s = serialzer.Serialize(listHourlyGraph.Select(x => new { device = x.Hour.ToString(), geekbench = x.Sales.ToString() } ));